# I can't connect to the access point made by WI-FI DIRECT via WIFI

Tags: android, wifi, wifi-direct, wifimanager, wifip2p

I created an access point with android WI-FI P2P APIs and i want to connect to it with another phone using WIFI(not wifi direct) and the following code :

```
WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
conf.SSID = "\"" + networkSSID + "\""; 
conf.preSharedKey = "\""+ networkPass +"\"";
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);
List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
for( WifiConfiguration i : list ) {
    if(i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals("\"" + networkSSID + "\"")) {
         wifiManager.disconnect();
         wifiManager.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
         wifiManager.reconnect();               

         break;
    }           
 }
```

and with the following permissions :

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

but it doesn't connect to that access point.
but sumsung wifi manager connects to it easily.
i tried many libraries to connect , but the result was same.
i thought that maybe because the access point does not have an internet connection i can't connect to it.
please help me i need to solve this issue for my application. tnks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed the issue and i want to share the solution with you.
i used WIFI DIRECT API to discover the access point and retrieve it's info like password to connect it but i realized that when you are using WIFI DIRECT API to discover services , you can't connect to an access point at the same time with the WIFI (i think it's bug).
**so you should stop the service discovery first and then connect to the access point.**
i used the following code :

```
public void connectToAccessPoint(GroupAccessPoint groupAccessPoint) {
    stopServiceDiscovery(new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            connect(groupAccessPoint);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int reason) {
            connect(groupAccessPoint);
        }
    });
}

public void stopServiceDiscovery(@Nullable WifiP2pManager.ActionListener stopDiscoveryListener) {
    if (wifiP2pManager == null) return;
    wifiP2pManager.clearServiceRequests(channel, new DefaultActionListener(actionListener, Action.CANCEL_DISCOVERING));
    wifiP2pManager.setDnsSdResponseListeners(channel, null, null);
    wifiP2pManager.stopPeerDiscovery(channel, stopDiscoveryListener);
}

private void connect(GroupAccessPoint groupAccessPoint) {
    WifiUtils.withContext(activity.getApplicationContext())
            .connectWith(groupAccessPoint.ssid, groupAccessPoint.password)
            .setTimeout(12000)
            .onConnectionResult(new ConnectionSuccessListener() {
                @Override
                public void success() {
                    actionListener.onSuccess(Action.JOIN_GROUP);
                }

                @Override
                public void failed(@NonNull ConnectionErrorCode errorCode) {
                    actionListener.onFailure(Action.JOIN_GROUP);
                }
            }).start();
}
```